# Is there a terminal emulator for linux that can highlight keywords for all the printed output

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator

I use mobaXterm on windows in my work laptop to ssh to linux machines. One feature that I like the best is that it highlights words such as error and warning in build output in red/blue colour. This is really helpful when I am running 8 jobs simultaneously for a build and an error occurs somewhere in the interlaced output. But I use Linux as the only OS on my personal laptop. Is a terminal with such feature available for Linux? Or is it possible to get this feature via some plugin? I do not want to redirect the output to other program everytime and would like the terminal emulator to do this. Currently I am using LXTerm and it is not possible there.

Comment: I use Moba at work, but solely Linux on my machines – so I know what you mean. Should be possible in any terminal with some (sourced) Bash stuff, but I didn't have time to dig into that yet. Reference from our sister site: [Colour highlighting output based on regex in shell](//stackoverflow.com/q/4267400/2533433). [ChromaTerm](https://github.com/hSaria/ChromaTerm) might be of help here, see [here](https://notx.ml/Own_projects/Highlighting_Cisco_keywords_or_output_on_Linux/) for an example setup.

Comment: [Linux terminal: Keyword highlighting similar to MobaXTerm without piping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492621/44425)

Answer (score 1):

Not a terminal emulator, and this might not help in your usecase,

but on Linux you can install the logfile colorizer [grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc) (with the package manager).

The you can define Bash aliases for often used commands, for example

`alias errorlog='grc tail -2000 /var/log/kern.log`

For more examples, see the bottom of the README file of the github repo that I've linked to.